# UIStoryboardSegue has retain-cycle with its destinationViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, retain-cycle

I'm driving a `UIStoryboardSegue` with a `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` that is based on a user gesture. If the gesture ends before it has reached a certain completion rate, the segue is canceled by calling `cancelInteractiveTransition` on the `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`. However, the presented view controller does not get deallocated, as it has a retain cycle with the `UIStoryboardSegue`, as depicted below.

I tested this with Apple's sample code on [Custom View Controller Presentations and Transitions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CustomTransitions/Introduction/Intro.html) and got the same problem. The image below is actually from their own project. Simply download the project, run it, and begin a segue but cancel it before it has completed. Repeat this 50 times and the Debug Memory Graph will show 50 leaked view controllers.

Are we supposed to nullify the destination view controller manually when we want to cancel the segue, or is this a bug in iOS? (I am running iOS10 on an iPhone 7 Plus).

[image]

Here is what profiling through Instruments show:

[image]

Comment: I have downloaded the project. How do you cancel the transition?

Comment: Choose the Swipe transition, and begin swiping left starting from the right edge. Only swipe a little bit, and then release. The segue will cancel, will controller B will be removed (but not deallocated).

Comment: I am running instruments right now and I see no leaks

Comment: gimme a sec ill check the memory graph

Comment: What if you look in the Debug Memory Graph?

Comment: Just checked the memory graph.. no leaks... Im running iOS 10.3 on iPhone 5

Comment: That's interesting, thanks for testing. I'm on 10.3.1, and I'm seeing leaks in both Memory Graph and Instruments. And even without looking at the leaks, you can just set a breakpoint in the second view controller's dealloc-method and see that it only gets called on the unwind segue, never when the presentation segue is canceled. ViewDidLoad is called, however, so there must a a leak.

Comment: @DanielLarsson, Have you managed to fix it? I have faced the same issue on iOS 11.